# Prism RequestNavigate from PrismApplication immediately on start

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

In **Prism 7** I can `RegisterForNavigation` and `RequestNavigate` from `IModule` like this:

```
public class ModuleAModule : IModule
{
    public void OnInitialized(IContainerProvider containerProvider)
    {
        var regionManager = containerProvider.Resolve<IRegionManager>();
        regionManager.RequestNavigate("ContentRegion", "PersonList");
    }

    public void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {
        containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<PersonList>();
    }
}
```

and I know that I can `RegisterForNavigation` from `PrismApplication` like this:

```
public partial class App : PrismApplication
{
    protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {
        containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<ViewA>();
    }
}
```

but how can I `RequestNavigate` from `PrismApplication` immediately on start?

I have tried this:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public MainWindowViewModel(IRegionManager regionManager)
    {
        regionManager.RequestNavigate("ContentRegion", "ViewA");
    }
}
```

but `this.regions.Count` is 0 in `RegionManager` from `Prism`

```
private IRegion GetRegionByName(string regionName)
{
    return this.regions.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Name == regionName);
}
```

`"ContentRegion"` definitely exists, because it works if I try from the `IModule` and I know that `RegisterTypes` from `PrismApplication` executes before the `MainWindowViewModel` constructor.

I don't know what I am missing and I can't find the answer in any examples or tutorials.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best bet is to override `OnInitialized` in your application and do the navigation there. You can access the container to fetch the region manager through the `Container` property.

If you use a bootstrapper, you can override `InitializeModules` and navigate there.